# Running all Coldfusion endpoints from CF-installed Tomcat wwwroot

Tags: tomcat, iis, coldfusion

Our CF web applications are currently being served through IIS7 which requires the wsconfig tool to create the connections between CF and a given site.  This requires restarting IIS each time a new site is created and also creates another "balance" to be maintained between two server applications (IIS/CF).

We're starting to lean heavily toward the single-page application so I'm wondering if it might be easier for us to simply use the Tomcat wwwroot folder for the backend "endpoints"?  Pardon the borrowing of App Engine terminology but that's essentially what we're looking to accomplish.  IIS would still serve the normal client pieces but all API calls would just go to Tomcat's `wwwroot/<projectName>`.  It seems that in this configuration, we'd get the best of both worlds - no need for context configurations in Tomcat and no restarts in IIS (or CF) when a new application backend is added.

I should also mention that these applications are internal and windows-authenticated.  In addition, no one will ever be required to access an application without going through the "pretty" IIS header.

I'm mainly curious to know if putting everything in one directory like this is a bad idea?  I mean, I know that the whole point of a wwwroot folder is to be just that.  I just want to be sure I'm not missing anything by not using formal contexts for each application.